# Pycharm Error - No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, pycharm

I have installed MySqldb as shown below:-

```
jab-MacBook-Pro-4:silkroute deb$ pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
Successfully installed MySQL-python-1.2.5
```

But still I am getting the error:-

[image]

```
python --version
Python 2.7.11
```

I am using version 2.7.10 in PyCharm

[image]

I have also installed MySQLDB as shown below:-

```
jab-MacBook-Pro-4:silkroute deb$ pip2.7 install MySQL-python
Requirement already satisfied: MySQL-python in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Can someone let me know how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Pycharm was not using the right python environment.You can change the project interpreter by setting Pycharm.
Step:

- File-> Settings
- In Popup menu:  Project-> Project Interpreter-> add  or create virtualenv environment

After changing project interpreter, the Pycharm has many function to use
[image: You can use Pycharm to install Package]

Comment: Still seeing the issue. Updated the question.

Comment: To check the site-packages if it is contain MySQLdb. You can use pycharm to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Open PyCharm, File>>Default Settings>>Project Interpreter>>Select the Interpreter you want to install the packages to, press the red '+' sign to the right, search the package and install.

This should most probably correct your error. You are better off creating a virtualenv though, will be really helpful. [Use this to get started](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple Python versions installed.

Use pip2.7 to see if this installs on the right python version.

Check this post: [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Comment: I tried doing `pip2.7 install MySQL-python`. The response I got :-
`Requirement already satisfied: MySQL-python in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Did you check if your pyCharm was using the right python environment? Check the other answer.

Comment: Updated the question.